# MongoDB aggregation error operation exceeded time limit

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I've been struggling to complete an aggregation process due to the timeout error and none of the solutions online have worked for me. I've reduced the workload as much as possible through `match`

Mongo version: 4.1.3
Using MongoDB Free tier

**Attempt:**

```
   return this.abyssBattleModel
      .aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            floor_level: floorLevel,
            battle_index: battleIndex,
          },
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'playercharacters',
            localField: 'party',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'party',
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            party: {
              $map: {
                input: '$party',
                as: 'pc',
                in: '$$pc.character',
              },
            },
            floor_level: 1,
            battle_index: 1,
            star: 1,
          },
        },
        {
          $match: {
            party: { $all: characterIds },
          },
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              party: '$party',
              floorLevel: '$floor_level',
              battleIndex: '$battle_index',
            },
            count: {
              $sum: 1,
            },
            avgStar: {
              $avg: '$star',
            },
            winCount: {
              $sum: {
                $cond: { if: { $eq: ['$star', 3] }, then: 1, else: 0 },
              },
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            count: -1,
          },
        },
        {
          $limit: limit,
        },
      ])
      .option({ maxTimeMS: 21600000, allowDiskUse: true, noCursorTimeout: true })
      .exec();
```

In this query the field `party` is an array of `PlayerCharacter` ObjectIds. A `PlayerCharacter` object has a field `character` which references a `Character` ObjectId. In this query I am using `$lookup` to change `party` to an array of `PlayerCharacter` ObjectIds to `Character` ObjectIds so that I can filter them by `Character` ObjectIds.

**Models**

```
// Filtered by floor_level and battle_index and party
// Party is an array of PlayerCharacter ObjectId
// which need to be joined with Character model to filter by Character id
export class AbyssBattle {
  @Field(() => String)
  _id: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Prop({ required: true })
  floor_level: string;

  @Field(() => Number)
  @Prop({ required: true })
  battle_index: number;

  @Field(() => Number)
  @Prop({ required: true })
  star: number;

  @Field(() => [String])
  @Prop({
    type: [MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId],
    ref: 'PlayerCharacter',
    required: true,
  })
  party: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId[];
}
```

```
export class PlayerCharacter {
  @Field(() => String)
  _id: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Prop({
    type: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Character',
    required: true,
  })
  character: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId;
}
```

Is there another way to increase the timeout or is this a limitation of MongoDB free tier that I'm unaware of? Is this purely an optimization issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are your indexes?

Comment: You don't need `party: {$map: ...}`, simply use `party: "$party.character"`

Comment: Apologies, updated the post with the models and additional details.

Comment: Try running the query with `explain`, that may help identify which part is slow.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from proper index on `{ floor_level: 1, battle_index: 1 }` you can try to optimize the `$lookup`:

```
{
   $lookup:
      {
         from: 'playercharacters',
         pipeline: [ 
            { $match: { _id: { $all: characterIds } } },
            { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$party",  "$$_id" ] } }
         ],
         as: 'party'
      }
}
```

Or as concise correlated subquery (requires MongoDB 5.0)

```
{
  $lookup: {
     from: "playercharacters",
     localField: "party",
     foreignField: "_id",
     pipeline: [ { $match: { _id: { $all: characterIds } } } ],
     as: "party"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$party",  "$$_id" ] } } works since a single ObjectId is being compared to an array of ObjectIds -- unless I'm misunderstanding what `$$_id` is supposed to represent?